# Embedded divs in header: css issue

Tags: html, css, divide

I am trying to create the following structure using embedded `div`s inside a `header`:

[image]

- The height and width of the red part is known and fix
- The height of the green rectangle is known and fix
- The overall width of the frame can vary, but is never smaller than the red part

I have tried with the following html code:

```
<header id="header">
  <div id="yellowAndGreen">
      <div id="yellow"></div>
      <div id="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="red"></div>
</header>
```

and the following CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 400px;  
}
#yellowAndGreen {

}

#yellow {    
    background-color: yelow;
}

#green {    
    background-color: green;
    height: 40px;
}

#red {    
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

but it does not work. I have created a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkmgn43a/2/). Can anyone modify it to create what I am looking for?

Comment: If the viewport drops below your `400px` header width, should the yellow and green be above or below the red?

Comment: 400px is a random size for the header, it could be anything bigger than the width of the red part. The width of the yellow and green should adapt to the width of the overall rectangle (i.e., minus the width of the red part).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wkmgn43a/6/

Comment: Rachel, there is a gap on the left of the red block...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `float:right;` to make the red box float to the right. You'll need to adjust the html:

```
<header id="header">
  <div id="alldivs">
      <div id="red"></div>
      <div id="yellow"></div>
      <div id="green"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

and the css:

```
#header {
    width: 400px;  
}
#yellow {    
    background-color: yellow;
    height:110px;
}

#green {    
    background-color: green;
    height: 40px;
}

#red {    
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    float:right;
}
```

Please note you had misspelled "yellow", and that you need to set a height for the yellow `<div>`.

Finally [here is the adjusted fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkmgn43a/4/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This uses flexbox, which has some support drop off on older browsers.  I've excluded vendor-specific attirbutes for simplicity.

```
#header {
    width: 400px;  
    display: flex;
}
#yellowAndGreen {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#yellow {    
    background-color: yellow;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#green {    
    background-color: green;
    height: 40px;
}

#red {    
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**No floats or flexbox necessary!**

Rearranged your HTML a bit. Set `#header` `background-color` to `red` and `min-width` so it will never be too small. Use `calc()` for `#yellow`'s width so that the background red of it's parent will always be 150px wide.

```css
#header {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 150px;
}

#yellow {
    height: 150px;
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
    background-color: yellow;
}

#green {    
    background-color: green;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
      <div id="yellow"></div>
      <div id="green"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: That's not really what they asked for - the red div contains the other two, they wanted 3 independent divs

Comment: Whoops!  Didn't see any content in the `div`s, so I assumed it didn't matter.